# using awk to read alternate lines by condition

Tags: unix, awk

I wish to use awk to perform the following task: By default, print the first line of each unique item on column 1. If there is MATCH1 or MATCH2 on column 2, print that line instead. If there is both MATCH1 or MATCH2 on column 2, print only the line with MATCH1, ie MATCH1 will be the priority.

```
A   1
A   2
A   3
A   MATCH1
A   5
A   6
B   1
B   MATCH2
B   3
B   MATCH1
B   5
C   1
C   MATCH2
C   3
C   4
D   1
D   2
```

Expected results:

```
A   MATCH1
B   MATCH1
C   MATCH2
D   1
```

How to? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO its highly encouraged to add efforts by OP in form of code in their questions, so kindly do add the same in your question(not my downvote btw).

Comment: I think awk can be quite awkward for the unwary, either your code is right, or your code generates nothing. anyway, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

This script generates the output you need:

```
{
   if (a[$1] == "") {
     a[$1] = $2;
   }
   if ($2 == "MATCH1") {
     a[$1] = $2;
   }
   if ($2 == "MATCH2" && a[$1] != "MATCH1") {
     a[$1] = $2;
   }
}


END {
   for (i in a) {
     print i " " a[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry the script generates the following results
A 1
B 1
C 1
D 1
where the above code is put in GNU nano as sample2.awk
cat test.txt | awk -f sample2.awk

Comment: I think you captured a "work in progress" version while I was still editing. I tested the final script on both a Linux debian and a Cygwin installation, and it worked correctly. Could you please copy the latest version and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Anonther version

```sh
awk '
    function r(arg) { gensub(/.*([0-9]+)$/, "\\1", "1", arg) }

    !a[$1] { a[$1] = $2 }

    $2 ~ /MATCH/{ 
        s=r(a[$1])
        m=r($2)
        if(s >= m || !a[$1]) {
            a[$1]=$2
        }
    }
    END {
        for(i in a) {
            print i, a[i]
        }
    }' log1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```sh
awk '
!($1 in a) || (a[$1] != "MATCH1" && $2 ~ /^MATCH[12]$/) {
   a[$1] = $2
}
END {
   for (i in a)
      print i, a[i]
}' file

A MATCH1
B MATCH1
C MATCH2
D 1
```